# How to correctly deal with floating point arithmetic in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

How to correctly add or subtract using floats?
For example how to perform:

```
2.4e-07 - 1e-8
```

so that it returns `2.3e-7` instead of `2.2999999999999997e-07`.

Converting to int first yields unexpected results, the below returns `2.2e-07`:

```
int(2.4e-07 * 1e8 - 1) * 1e-8
```

Similarly,

```
(2.4e-07 * 1e8 - 1) * 1e-8
```

returns `2.2999999999999997e-07`.

How to perform subtraction and addition of numbers with 8 decimal point precision?

`2.2999999999999997e-07` is not sufficient as the number is used as a lookup in a dictionary, and the key is `2.3e-7`. This means that any value other than `2.3e-7` results in an incorrect lookup.

Comment: If you need exact decimal values you should think whether floating point variables are the right tool for the job since they are always an approximation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: You are already performing the addition with much better than 8 decimal point precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html) data type (it is present in the stardard installation of Python), because it uses fixed precision to avoid just the differences you are talking about.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> x = Decimal('2.4e-7')
>>> x
Decimal('2.4E-7')
>>> y = Decimal('1e-8')
>>> y
Decimal('1E-8')
>>> x - y
Decimal('2.3E-7')
```

Comment: How to deal with this when the original data is a float instead of a string? Is this a good approach `Decimal('%.8f' % 2.4e-7) - Decimal('%.8f' % 1e-8)` or is there a more correct/better way of doing it?

Comment: @Greg yes, that string formatting is probably your best bet to get Decimal objects

Answer (score 1):

It's really just a way of skirting around the issue of floating point arithmetic, but I suggest using the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) package from the standard library. It lets you do exact floating point math.

Using your example,

```
$ from decimal import Decimal
$ x = Decimal('2.4e-7')
$ y = Decimal('1e-8')
$ x-y
Decimal('2.3E-7')
```

It's worth noting that `Decimal` objects are different than the `float` built-in, but they are mostly interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is what you are looking for but you can try that kind of thing:

```
a = 0.555555555
a = float("{0:.2f}".format(a))
>>> 0.56
```

I hope it will help you!

Adrien