# wrong loop result - python

Tags: python, for-loop, math

I needed to make a program that iterates over values from **x1** to **x2** in **dx** increments. But I can't figure out how it works

```
a = 1

while a < 2:
    print(a)
    a += 0.1
```

I got this result.

```
1
1.1
1.2000000000000002
1.3000000000000003
1.4000000000000004
1.5000000000000004
1.6000000000000005
1.7000000000000006
1.8000000000000007
1.9000000000000008
```

but wanted to get this result.

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55517241/how-to-correctly-deal-with-floating-point-arithmetic-in-python

Comment: also https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html